# Running into Issues with Xamarin Binding Library with 3rd party component Slyce

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, objective-sharpie

I'm having some challenges trying to get a binding libraries made for this 3rd party product called Slyce... there sdks are on GitHub

https://github.com/Slyce-Inc/Slyce-Android-SDK

https://github.com/Slyce-Inc/Slyce-iOS-SDK

Using the meta file below on the Android side i can get it to compile but i can't get my project to build with the reference attached i get the following errors.

> CameraFrame_ReleaseListenerImplementor.java(40,40): Error:  error:
>   ReleaseListener has protected access in CameraFrame
>           com.android.slyce.scanner.CameraFrame.ReleaseListener
>
> CameraInstance_ListenerImplementor.java(43,43): Error:  error:
>   Listener has protected access in CameraInstance
>           com.android.slyce.scanner.CameraInstance.Listener

```
meta file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>

    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.communication']/interface[@name='CommManager.On2DSearchListener']"    name="argsType">OnTwoDSearchListener</attr>

    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.utils']/class[@name='Constants']/field[@name='_1D']" 
    name="managedName">OneD</attr>

      <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.utils']/class[@name='Constants']/field[@name='_2D']" 
    name="managedName">TwoD</attr>

      <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.utils']/class[@name='Constants']/field[@name='_3D']" 
    name="managedName">ThreeD</attr>

    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.utils']/class[@name='BarcodeHelper.ScannerType']/field[@name='_2D']" 
    name="managedName">TwoD</attr>

    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.utils']/class[@name='BarcodeHelper.ScannerType']/field[@name='_3D']" 
    name="managedName">ThreeD</attr>


<!--
    Volley Stuff
    -->
    <!-- Change the name of the Request interface -->

    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.volley']/interface[@name='Request.Method']" name="managedName">RequestMethod</attr>

    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.volley']/class[@name='Request']/method[@name='compareTo' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='com.android.volley.Request&lt;T&gt;']]/parameter[1]" name="managedType">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.volley.toolbox']/class[@name='ImageRequest']/method[@name='deliverResponse' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='android.graphics.Bitmap']]/parameter[1]" name="managedType">Java.Lang.Object</attr>

    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.android.volley.toolbox']/class[@name='JsonRequest']/method[@name='parseNetworkResponse' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='com.android.volley.NetworkResponse']]"/>

<!--     OnSlyceCameraListener-->

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceCameraListener']/method[@name='onCameraBarcodeDetected']" name="argsType">OnSlyceCameraListener_onCameraBarcodeDetected</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceCameraListener']/method[@name='onCameraBarcodeInfoReceived']" name="argsType">OnSlyceCameraListener_onCameraBarcodeInfoReceived</attr>

<!--        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceCameraListener']/method[@name='onCameraFinished']" name="argsType">OnSlyceCameraListener_onCameraFinished</attr>-->

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceCameraListener']/method[@name='onCameraImageDetected']" name="argsType">OnSlyceCameraListener_onCameraImageDetected</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceCameraListener']/method[@name='onCameraImageInfoReceived']" name="argsType">OnSlyceCameraListener_onCameraImageInfoReceived</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceCameraListener']/method[@name='onCameraPreviewMode']" name="argsType">OnSlyceCameraListener_onCameraPreviewMode</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceCameraListener']/method[@name='onCameraResultsReceived' ]" name="argsType">OnSlyceCameraListener_onCameraResultsReceived</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceCameraListener']/method[@name='onCameraSlyceProgress']" name="argsType">OnSlyceCameraListener_onCameraSlyceProgress</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceCameraListener']/method[@name='onCameraSlyceRequestStage' ]" name="argsType">OnSlyceCameraListener_onCameraSlyceRequestStage</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceCameraListener']/method[@name='onProgressExt']" name="argsType">OnSlyceCameraListener_onProgressExt</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceCameraListener']/method[@name='onResultsReceivedExt']" name="argsType">OnSlyceCameraListener_onResultsReceivedExt</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceCameraListener']/method[@name='onSlyceCameraError' ]" name="argsType">OnSlyceCameraListener_onSlyceCameraError</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceCameraListener']/method[@name='onSnap']" name="argsType">OnSlyceCameraListener_onSnap</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceCameraListener']/method[@name='onTap']" name="argsType">OnSlyceCameraListener_onTap</attr>

<!--OnSlyceRequestListener -->

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceRequestListener']/method[@name='onCameraBarcodeDetected']" name="argsType">OnSlyceRequestListener_onCameraBarcodeDetected</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceRequestListener']/method[@name='onCameraBarcodeInfoReceived']" name="argsType">OnSlyceRequestListener_onCameraBarcodeInfoReceived</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceRequestListener']/method[@name='onCameraFinished']" name="argsType">OnSlyceRequestListener_onCameraFinished</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceRequestListener']/method[@name='onCameraImageDetected']" name="argsType">OnSlyceRequestListener_onCameraImageDetected</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceRequestListener']/method[@name='onCameraImageInfoReceived']" name="argsType">OnSlyceRequestListener_onCameraImageInfoReceived</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceRequestListener']/method[@name='onCameraPreviewMode']" name="argsType">OnSlyceRequestListener_onCameraPreviewMode</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceRequestListener']/method[@name='onCameraResultsReceived' ]" name="argsType">OnSlyceRequestListener_onCameraResultsReceived</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceRequestListener']/method[@name='onCameraSlyceProgress']" name="argsType">OnSlyceRequestListener_onCameraSlyceProgress</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceRequestListener']/method[@name='onCameraSlyceRequestStage' ]" name="argsType">OnSlyceRequestListener_onCameraSlyceRequestStage</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceRequestListener']/method[@name='onProgressExt']" name="argsType">OnSlyceRequestListener_onProgressExt</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceRequestListener']/method[@name='onResultsReceivedExt']" name="argsType">OnSlyceRequestListener_onResultsReceivedExt</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceRequestListener']/method[@name='onSlyceCameraError' ]" name="argsType">OnSlyceRequestListener_onSlyceCameraError</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceRequestListener']/method[@name='onSnap']" name="argsType">OnSlyceRequestListener_onSnap</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.listeners']/interface[@name='OnSlyceRequestListener']/method[@name='onTap']" name="argsType">OnSlyceRequestListener_onTap</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.scanner']/interface[@name='CameraFrame.ReleaseListener']" name="visibility">public</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.crop']/class[@name='ImageViewTouchBase']" name="visibility">public</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.slyce.scanner']/interface[@name='CameraInstance']" name="visibility">public</attr>

        <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.volley']/class[@name='Request']/method[@name='deliverResponse']" name="abstract">false</attr>    
</metadata>
```

On the IOS side, Here is the output of Sharpie when trying to use the Framework

```
$ sharpie bind -framework SlyceSDK.framework 
Parsing 1 header files...

Binding...
  no types were parsed that could be bound

Done. Exiting with error code 1.
```

Comment: Hey, any solution found?

Comment: they open sourced the bindings https://github.com/Slyce-Inc/Xamarin.Slyce

Comment: I was talking about sharpie :) I am trying to bind the Twitter Kit